# Convert many .pages documents to Word

Tags: macos, ms-office, pages

How to convert many .pages documents to later open them with Word using Mac?

Answer (score 1):

This is an AppleScript which will export all Pages documents in a folder into PDFs.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set fileslist to (every file of folder POSIX file ¬
        "/path/to/folder") as alias list
end tell
tell application "Pages"
    repeat with f in fileslist
        set doc to open f
        export doc ¬
            to (path to downloads folder as string) ¬
                & (name of doc) ¬
                & ".pdf" ¬
            as PDF
        close doc
    end repeat
end tell
```

Replace `/path/to/folder` with the path to the containing folder of just Pages documents.
This script exports to the Downloads folder. Alter as necessary.

Comment: Where do you run this script?

Comment: @Andre You can use Script Editor.app in the /Applications/Utilities/ folder